HTML input file takes long time to open with Firefox and Ubuntu when running from embedded webserver
On my ESP32 Arduino application I run a simple form to upload a file:


function uploadFile() {
  let file = document.getElementById("file1").files[0];
  let formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file1", file);
  let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "/");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function errorHandler(event) {}

function abortHandler(event) {}
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
</form>



The code to create the server is pretty standard:
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

// ...

AsyncWebServer _server;

MDNS.begin("my app");
MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);

_server.onFileUpload(handleUpload);

_server.serveStatic("/", LittleFS, "/www")
    .setDefaultFile("index.html")
    .setTemplateProcessor(std::bind(&WebApp::processor, this, std::placeholders::_1));

_server.onNotFound([](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{ 
    request->send(404); 
});

_server.begin();

// ...

void handleUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, String filename, size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) 
{
  if (!index) 
  {
    request->_tempFile = LittleFS.open("/" + filename, "w");
  }
  
  if (len) 
  {
    request->_tempFile.write(data, len);
  }

  if (final) 
  {
    request->_tempFile.close();
    request->redirect("/");
  }
}

When I click on the browse item in Ubuntu 23.04 and Firefox, it takes a very long time to open the file dialog (over 10 seconds). And any change in the current directory takes several seconds.
Using Firefox on mobile (Android) does not show this issue or even using Chrome on Ubuntu.
I don't think the firmware code is involved since it should be handled browser side.
BUT, the snippet above runs fine from this site, with the same browsers.
Is there anything I could to in the HTML page to improve this odd behavior?
